# Python3: how to select columns I want and avoid keyerror if they are absent

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

I have some categorical values

```
E.g. things = 'cat', dog', 'pen', 'bar'
```

Which I encode to numerical values via OneHotEncoding:

```
car dog pen bar
1   1   1   1
```

I want to use some of the columns in my dataset.

E.g. car dog pen and not bar.

I do it by defining the specific columns:

```
dataset = dataset[['car', 'dog', 'pen']]
```

But sometimes some of the columns I want - are absent in my dataset, e.g. 'car'

Then Python prints the error:

```
KeyError: "['car'] not in index"
```

How can I solve the problem:

1. to have the columns I want
2. to avoid the error if the columns I want are absent

Comment: You mention “dataset” so it seems like you are referring to Pandas. Is that the case? Can you show how you originally created `dataset` so that your issue is reproducible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some sanity checks. An example is the following function:

```
def custom_dataset(dataset, req_cols):
    in_, out_ = [], []
    if isinstance(dataset, pd.DataFrame):  # optional
        for col in req_cols:  # check for every existing column
            if col in dataset.columns:
                in_.append(col)  # append those that are in (i.e. valid)
            else:
                out_.append(col)  # append those that are NOT in (i.e. invalid)
    return dataset[in_] if in_ else None, out_ if out_ else None
```

As you can see, it returns a tuple of two elements:

1. The dataset required of the existing columns only, otherwise it returns None (so you can check for None on the result to avoid errors).
2. A list of non-found columns (for your records). Otherwise, if all found, it returns None.

Even if the dataset is not an instance of `DataFrame` or the user did not provide any columns to collect, the function won't throw an error but rather it will return `(None, None)`.

Comment: Yahya, thank you very much for the great function. It is exactly what I need.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Yahya, on the basis of your function I 1) create the list of required columns which is in the dataset 2) use this list for selection: [col for col in col_calc if col in df.columns]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following
`dataset.iloc[:,dataset.columns!="bar"]`

Comment: Akshat2249, thank you very much. In fact, there are a lot of the columns I don't want to use. It will be harder to define the columns I don't want to use, then I want to use. Moreover, the columns I don't want to use also can be absent and not absent. It depends on the dataset size.